# newInstance() cannot find constructor that exist

Tags: java, class, reflection, nosuchmethoderror

I think that I am missing something. I am trying to do next thing:

```
Class.forName(className).getConstructor(getParameterTypes(parameters)).newInstance(parameters);
```

I am getting error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: MyClass.<init>(java.lang.Class)
```

My class name is full class name(with packages). Method getParameterTypes is returning class java.lang.Class. parameters variable is type of Class and in MyClass I have constructor that is accepting Class. Do someone know what is the problem?

Comment: Can you paste code of your class?
exception is due to your getParameterTypes() is not returning expected parameters. Your code can give better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidently figured out solution, wanted to make temp solution. xD Problem was that constructor was protected, not public.